# Mongoose pre save hook not called with discriminator class

Tags: mongoose, save, hook

It seems that pre save hook is not called on the base schema class in case of discriminator class.

On contrary, pre validate hook is well called.

Am I right ? Is there any reason for not calling the pre save hook on base Schema ?

JM.